# Use Vue component after Webpack build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a CMS that delivers static HTML pages. For that CMS, I want to develop components with Vue that then can be used in the CMS individually.
As I understood, Vue is the perfect solution for that.

As TypeScript gets more and more common, I want to use TypeScript with Babel and Webpack, so the CLI project gave me a perfect boilerplate.

When I run `npm run build`, I get an `index.html` in the `dist` folder with my `<div id="app"></div>`-container. This could be my root element/template in CMS, and then just pass the components in it.

Sadly, everything in the app-container is rendered out.

I already registered my components inside the `main.ts` file, and removed the line `render: (h)=>h(App)`, but it also replaces my container contents.

*Main.ts:*

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import ButtonLink from './components/ButtonLink.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

// Adding the component to my Vue context
Vue.component('ButtonLink', ButtonLink);

new Vue({
  // render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Excerpt of index.html in dist dir:

```html
 <div id=app>
        <ButtonLink href="https://google.com">A link </ButtonLink>
    </div>
```

Link to full project: https://gitlab.com/cedricwe/vue-problem/tree/master

What did I do wrong? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using in-DOM templates *without* the runtime compiler, which would yield this browser console warning:

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

(found in <Root>)
```

The runtime compiler is excluded by default to reduce the bundle size. You could enable it in a Vue CLI project with the [`runtimeCompiler`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler) flag in `vue.config.js` in the root of your project:

```js
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is provide your Vue instance a "mounting point". In this case we normally use the [`el` option](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el) something along the lines of this would work instead:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import ButtonLink from './components/ButtonLink.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
    el: '#app', // mounts this instance to #app but doesn't render it
    components: {
        ButtonLink // optionally have it local to your instance vs global
    }
});
```